# Automatically deploy Kafka Stream app

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm just starting with Kafka and Kafka Streaming Applications. I wrote a Kafka Stream App that consumes from one topic, process this messages, and send them to another topic.

To the best of my knowledge, the only ways that I have found to run this Kafka Stream App coded are:

- Run Java Class from IDE.
- Generate `*.jar` file and run it from prompt.

I would like to know if there is any way to automatically run Kafka Streaming Applications on Kafka server startup. For example: copy the `*.jar` file to some folder of my Kafka installation, and automatically run this stream app when I start my Kafka server.

Comment: Note: it's not recommend to run Kafka Streams application on the same hardware as your brokers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Kafka broker (server) and your Kafka Streams application are independent from one another. You can start them however you manage processes on your server, whether it's something like initd or systemd, or container-based solutions like Docker or Kubernetes.

In my experience, if your streams application starts well before your broker or ZooKeeper, then it may time out waiting for them to come online. So you may need to configure the streams process to restart in such a situation.

Comment: I know that my Kafka Stream App can be running the whole time in a container-based solution, but the point is that I would like to know if there is any way to run it among with the Kafka broker itself automatically on startup. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't understand "is it possible?" Yes, it's possible: when you start the broker, in the next command start the streams application. What am I missing in your question? If you run it, you run it. If you don't, you don't.  What do you mean "automatically?" That is entirely dependent on your deployment mechanism. The broker and your Kafka Streams app have nothing to do intrinsically with each other, so you can run them automatically insofar as your deployment apparatus facilitates deployment.

Comment: I refeer to make/turn this Kafka Stream App to something "native" with Kafka installation, without the need of run the Kafka Stream App from prompt or command line. Probably the solution that I need is to create an script that runs the required infraestructure (Zookeeper, Kafka, etc...) and, then, run the Kafka Stream App in order to deploy all this automatically.

Comment: I think I understand. Yeah there’s no “native” way to run it with or as part of the kafka broker. Your suggested script makes sense. However you start zookeeper and kafka... then just start your Streams app.